# Act on will vs at will

Tags: meaning

Can it mean the same as 'act at will', like whenever it pleases one? Can you think of a context when 'act on will' could be used?

Answer (score 1):

The difference seems to lie in the specific requirements of the action implied by the preposition.

"Act at will" refers to the *timeframe* in which someone may act; i.e. starting at the moment of speaking, the subject has discretion to perform the action when they see fit. A restatement of "Act at will" might be: "Act when you choose to."
"Fire at will" is a commonly-encountered analogous example.

"Act on will" seems to refer to the *action itself*. That is, the subject may act in whatever manner suits them. A restatement might be: "Act however you want to."

"Act on will" would be somewhat unwieldy, and not intuitive to a reader, but it might find use in dialogue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perfect it is. :)